# How to make gradient line in CSS

Tags: html, css, gradient

How can I make this two gradient lines(black to white) like this photo: [View this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQh7X.png)

Here is my code:

```
.container-fluid {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 470px;
    background-image:url("images.jpg");
    background-position: 10px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

Comment: What gradient are you seeing? And have you tried looking for a CSS gradient generator? And please don't rollback edits to your question that improve your question (it's your prerogative, you're allowed to do so), given that the image is more use to those people trying to help you if it's easy to see I don't see why you would want to  hide it.

Comment: See my picture. How I can use this CSS gradient generator? I don't know how to upload picture direct, without having to use a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.a {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black, transparent 70px, transparent 330px, black, black 400px),
      url("https://unsplash.it/610/400");

}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  
</div>
```